# If text overflows parent element, add class

Tags: jquery

I have en element which potentially could contain a long text. I'm looking for a jQuery function to detect if the text overflows the width or height of the element, and if it does, a class must be added to the parent element. (I'm not looking for the text-ellipsis property.)

How can this be done? I have started a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6mL79xdL/1/). Obviously, it doesn't work with `$(elm).text().width()`. How to get the width of text()?

Comment: Guess this is not possible.

Comment: It better be done with proper CSS styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clone` to a temporary element, change the `styles` and compare the scales with original element, finally deleted that temp object and return the compared result.

```js
$.expr[':'].truncated = function (obj) {
  var $this = $(obj);
  var $c = $this
    .clone()
    .css({
      display: 'inline',
      width: 'auto',
      visibility: 'hidden'
    })
    .appendTo('body');

  var c_width = $c.width();
  $c.remove();

  if (c_width > $this.width())
    return true;
  else
    return false;
};
$(".title:truncated").addClass("text-style");
```

```css
.title {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-style {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">A very long title title title - if I break I must have the class "text-style" appended</div>
<div class="title">A very long title title title </div>
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/6mL79xdL/8